# java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read data from elastic by using Scala spark, But it throw error message like
java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JListWrapper is not a valid external type for schema of string.
Do we have any alternate way to do the operation by using scala spark with elastic search.

[image]

Databricks- 9.1 LTS spark-3.1.2, Scala 2.12

Code:

```scala
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY") 

val reader = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes","..*.*")
  .option("es.net.http.auth.user", elasticUsername)
  .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", elasticPassword) 
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
  .option("es.resource", indexName)
  .option("es.read.field.exclude", excludeFields)
  .option("es.read.field.as.array.include", arrayFields)
  .option("es.query", elasticQueryString)
  .option("es.scroll.size","10000")
  .option("es.field.read.empty.as.null", "no")
```

Comment: provide versions of databricks runtime, elasticsearch connector, and also the code that you're using

Comment: Databricks- 9.1 LTS spark-3.1.2, Scala 2.12

code:
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
val reader = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes","*.*.*.*")
.option("es.net.http.auth.user", elasticUsername).option("es.net.http.auth.pass", elasticPassword)
.option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true").option("es.resource", indexName).option("es.read.field.exclude", excludeFields)
.option("es.read.field.as.array.include", arrayFields).option("es.query", elasticQueryString).option("es.scroll.size","10000")
.option("es.field.read.empty.as.null", "no")

Comment: What is the version of the Elasticsearch connector?

Comment: I am not sure, how do I check connector version, Could you pls help me on that?

Comment: Check cluster/job ui

Comment: I am using these dependencies, But i am not sure which one is used for elastic connect, How do i find it?

elasticsearch_core_7_10_1.jar
elasticsearch_7_10_1.jar
elasticsearch_x_content_7_10_1.jar
elasticsearch_spark_20_2_12_7_12_0.jar
elasticsearch_rest_client_7_10_2.jar
elasticsearch_rest_high_level_client_7_10_2.jar
elasticsearch==7.10.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247218/discussion-between-programmer-and-alex-ott).

Comment: we are using elasticsearch_core_7_10_1

Answer (score 1):

This exception is raised because among the fields that are read with the Spark application using `elasticsearch-hadoop` at least one has a value that is an array while it is not specified.

The fix is to put the field name in:

> es.read.field.as.array.include

Read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-field-info) of this configuration for more details.

Effectively a `field=<name,value>` in Elasticsearch can take the values:
`missing`, `null`, `value` or `array[value]`. The Elasticsearch mapping of an index does not allow defining a constraint on it, while Spark needs to have this information to build the schema of the DataFrame.

Read the field data types about [Arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).

Note: If you do it, all values read from this field will be `array[value]` even if the field has hybrid values in Elasticsearch: `value or array[value]` (a `missing` value will be considered as `null`). In this last case, another solution is to rewrite the docs where this field takes a not-wished value to have only `array[value]` or only `value` and not both.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using incorrect version of Elasticsearch library. If you use `elasticsearch_spark_20_2_12_7_12_0`, then it's a version that is compiled for Spark 2.4 (you can check on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.12/7.12.0)).

Instead you need to take a [version compiled against Spark 3.x](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-30), with name starting with `elasticsearch_spark_30` - not sure although which version to recommend, as 7.x are compiled against Spark 3.0, and 8.1+ are against - 3.2.x

I would also recommend to use Maven coordinates instead of attaching jar libraries to a cluster - in this case, cluster manager will fetch all necessary dependencies.

Comment: I found one observation:
1. the data which present in elastic search as array of, But when I read same data, i could see the Dataframe schema as string. and i read as a sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") I am not sure, due to this this error is occur?
Could you help me here.